# how to get record when second inner join fail

Tags: mysql, sql

users table

```
| id    | name     |  supplier_id| vendor_id |
|:------|:---------|:---------|:--------|
|1      |user1     |5         |1        |
|2      |user2     |5         |0       |
```

suppliers table

```
| id    | name     | 
|:------|:---------|
|1      |test supplier|
```

vendors table

```
| id    | name     | 
|:------|:---------|
|1      |testvendor|
```

i try to perform this query

```
select * 
from users 
INNER JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = users.suppliers_id 
INNER JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = users.vedoer_id
```

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in the second join.

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the record even if a inner join is returning nothing you must not use a inner join. use a left join instead

```
select * 
from users 
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = users.suppliers_id 
LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = users.vedoer_id
```

Comment: thank a lot for you valuable solution